# Exclude authors IDs from WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, functions, author

I am using this code, trying to exclude specific authors from `WP_Query`, however the author IDs in the array are not being excluded. Any ideas please?

```php
<?php
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array('who' => 'authors')
    ),
    array( 'author__not_in' => array(10, 3, 4) )
);
$site_url = get_site_url();
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exclude specific authors from `WP_Query`

You can do it like so:

```php
$args = array(
    'author__not_in' => array( 10, 3, 4 ),
);
$posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But if you meant "from `WP_User_Query`", then in `WP_User_Query`, you should use the `exclude` parameter, and that `array('who' => 'authors')` shouldn't be in `meta_query`:

```php
$args = array(
    'exclude' => array( 10, 3, 4 ), // not author__not_in
    'who'     => 'authors',         // not in meta_query
);
$users_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

For the full list of parameters, refer to [`WP_User_Query::prepare_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/) for `WP_User_Query`, or [`WP_Query::parse_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) for `WP_Query`.